# Syntax check for SQL query

Tags: mysql, replace, set

I am no expert. PhpMyAdmin keeps telling me the following code has the wrong syntax. Can you help me? Thanks!

```
UPDATE jos_content SET fulltext = REPLACE(fulltext,'<img alt="chiocciola" src="images/stories/chiocciola.gif" width="9" height="8" />','@')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FULLTEXT is MySQL [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html), it should be quoted with backtick character '`' -

```
UPDATE jos_content SET `fulltext` = REPLACE(`fulltext`, '<img alt="chiocciola" src="images/stories/chiocciola.gif" width="9" height="8" />', '@')
```